# How to share/Reassign analog pin for two Adafruit libraries for two adafruit hardware

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit

I'm attempting to use the Adafruit BMP180 and Adafruit 16x2 RGB LCD Display together on the same Arduino Uno R1. Both the pieces of hardware and their libraries use Analog Pin 4 and 5. Is there any way to reassign the pins for one of the libraries so I can use both of the parts together?

Here are the libraries I am using:

Adafruit BMP180/BMP085:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BMP085_Unified and https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-BMP085-Library

Adafruit 16x2 RGB LCD Display:
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-RGB-LCD-Shield-Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are using I2C (which i think they are), then it doesn't matter, because I2C is just a transfer protocol. In theory, you could have hundreds of devices using those pins, and have everything working fine. Just try using both, and tell me if anything doesn't work.